# jQuery find() until?

Tags: jquery

I'm going through a form checking values but I need to stop before a specific element (#before)

```
$('#before').closest('form').find('.reqd').each(function() {
    //chacks input
});
```

I need this to stop before or even better after it reaches #before. I read about nextUntil() but it seems only to work for sibling elements. I need to check all .reqd elements in the form before #before

I bet I'm missing some really simple way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried `return false;` inside your `each(..)`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to return false.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want. Like BNL said, some html would be helpful. If you want the element before `#before` you could just do `$('#before').prev()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

returning false within an each loop will exit the each loop.

```
$('#before').closest('form').find('.reqd').each(function() {
  // your code here
  if (this.id === "before") {
    // end each loop after processing #before
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: but #before might not be of .reqd

Comment: ok, I did it by simply find(':input') and then checking if it hasClass('.reqd'). Thanks for not asking me to post HTML! :)