# jQuery: find() children until a certain threshold element is encountered

Tags: jquery

I have a nested table structure like

```html
<table>
    <td id="first">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input name=1>
        </div>
        <input name=2>
        <table>
            <td id="second">
                <input name=3>
```

I have jQuery selection `$("#first")`. I'd like to traverse and `find()` all children `<input>s` within this `<td>` context, but not to descent into the nested `<table>`s.

So I need a jQuery trick which

- Will `find()` all children elements of a certain element
- Will descent n levels down in DOM tree
- But will stop descending if certain a element (`<table>`) is encountered, so that the selector doesn't select inputs of a nested tables (which will be handled separately)
- There could be any number of nested `<table>` levels, so the solution should work no matter how many parent `<table>` or children `<table>` are encountered within the scope of $("#first") `<td>` or any other `<td>`

I checked other jQuery find until questions. They have answers, but seems like they do not fill the last criteria

Comment: Do you think your table structure is fine here?

Comment: Whether the structure is done using `<table>` or some other element is naturally irrelevant for the question

Comment: I asked because your `input` tags are not well formed also `tr` is missing.

Comment: @freebird i think its just a hastily thrown together code example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159478/skip-recursion-in-jquery-find-for-a-selector/24215566?noredirect=1#comment37410122_24215566). I ended up finally figuring out a plugin on my own after going back and forth with some people trying to think of a find selector.

**USAGE :**
`ExclusiveInputs = $('#first').findExclude('input','table');`

```
// Find-like method which masks any descendant
// branches matching the Mask argument.
$.fn.findExclude = function( Selector, Mask, result){

    // Default result to an empty jQuery object if not provided
    var result = typeof result !== 'undefined' ?
                result :
                new jQuery();

    // Iterate through all children, except those match Mask
    this.children().each(function(){

        var thisObject = jQuery( this );
        if( thisObject.is( Selector ) ) 
            result.push( this );

        // Recursively seek children without Mask
        if( !thisObject.is( Mask ) )
            thisObject.findExclude( Selector, Mask, result );
    });

    return result;
}
```

*(Condensed Version)*:

```
$.fn.findExclude = function( selector, mask, result )
{
    var result = typeof result !== 'undefined' ? result : new jQuery();
    this.children().each( function(){
        var thisObject = jQuery( this );
        if( thisObject.is( selector ) ) 
            result.push( this );
        if( !thisObject.is( mask ) )
            thisObject.findExclude( selector, mask, result );
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> *Update:* Let's have another take at this.

Basically, you want to match all the `<input>` elements that are descendants of `#first` and that are not children of `<td>` elements nested more than one level deep under `#first`.

(I'm not sure about that last `under #first` part, but implementing it allows us to support `<td>` elements above `#first` in the ancestor chain.)

Technically, the following selector alone should fulfill your requirements:

```
var inputs = $("#first td:not(#first td td) > input");
```

If this does not work in your browser (Sizzle should be up to the task I think, but complex selectors like `:not()` are always tricky), you can delegate the processing to jQuery methods:

```
var inputs = $("#first td").not("#first td td").children("input");
```

---

> Original answer follows:

You can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude `<input>` elements that have more than one `<td>` ancestor:

```
var firstLevelCells = $("#first").find("input").not("td td input");
```

Comment: I don't get it; wouldn't this need to be `$("#first").find("input").not("td td input")`?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I lost track of the actual element to match along the way. Answer updated accordingly, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 2):

eh, i have a better idea..

```
var badTable = "table.bad"; //the one you want to avoid
var $goodInputs = $("#first").find('input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest(badTable).length == 0;
});
```

this may or may not be fast enough for you. it depends on your DOM which you do not want to talk about ;)

if its slow, just write the code for your algorithm by hand. There isnt a selector shortcut.

Comment: As the question tells, you cannot identify which table is "bad" from the context, but it must work with any nesting level without special class markers

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and clean utility function to do what you're looking for:

```js
// finds the selector, but excludes any matches found under the mask
$.fn.findExclude = function(selector, mask) {
    return this.find(selector).not(this.find(mask).find(selector))
}
```

In your case, you could call it like this:

```js
$("#first").findExclude("input", "table")
```

Which will find any `input` elements, but exclude those found as descendents of `table`.

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
// finds the selector, but excludes any matches found under the mask
$.fn.findExclude = function(selector, mask) {
    return this.find(selector).not(this.find(mask).find(selector))
}

$("#first").findExclude("input", "table").css({background:"red"})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <td id="first">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input value=1 />
    </div>
    <input value=2>
    <table>
      <td id="second">
        <input value=3 />
      </td>
    </table>
  </td>
</table>
```

#### Further Reading

- [Skip recursion in jQuery.find() for a selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159478/1366033)
- [jQuery find() until?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573751/1366033)
- [Is it possible to prevent jQuery.find() from searching below certain nodes of the DOM tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119674/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was still challenged to do something without an extension loop or having the exact structure of the DOM. In my case I had already a reference to the element '#first' which if you don't we could get it for example with an each (even if it is only one object). The trick is to go back up the tree with parentsuntil and stop at your top element to see if there is any intermediate element satisfying the conditionn.

Using the shorthand lambda notation for the functions (as you can write in typescript) this would lead to this:

```
$('#first').each((idx, f) => $(f).find('input').filter((idx2, inp) => $(inp).parentsUntil(f, 'table').length == 0)
```

It might not be the most efficient way (as you first select everything to then throw away elements by mounting up the DOM-tree again, but it is compact and fairly generic.