# How can I filter out a subtree and then search in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given `$('#test')` and the following DOM, how can I select the corresponding `ted-collapse`?

```
<div id='test' class='ted-panel'>
  <div class='ted-collapse'></div>

  <div class='ted-panel'>
    <div class='ted-collapse'></div>
    <div class='ted-collapse'></div>
    <div class='ted-collapse'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

- The corresponding `.ted-collapse` is the element that's a child of the current `.ted-panel` and *not* a child of any nested `.ted-panel`
- `.ted-collapse` is not guaranteed to be an immediate child of `.ted-panel`

Essentially, I want to (1) filter out any children `.ted-panel`s, then (2) `.find('.ted-collapse)`.

---

Here's a one-line solution based on one of the comments:

```
$('#test').not($('#test').find('.ted-collapse'))
```

Comment: perhaps, someone didn't understand...

Comment: it easier to let us know what you trying to do

Comment: `$('#test .ted-collapse').not('#test>.ted-panel .ted-collapse')`???

Comment: It just seems like you really have no idea what the markup will look like, and adding the same classes over and over, and then not being able to use them, seems silly !

Comment: @Bhojendra - C-Link Nepal nope: http://jsbin.com/qulili/2/

Comment: Is that what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314604/2324107

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I think so!

Comment: @SamSelikoff here in action : http://jsbin.com/xelitoteva/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @SamSelikoff if that was really your problem, tell me and i'll close it as duplicated.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I suppose it is the same, though I searched and couldn't find it. I was looking for "skip subtree"

Comment: @SamSelikoff Yeah, it is not a "popular question", that's why it doesn't always show in your such. But marking them as duplicated help referencing 1 question instead of X numbers. Well, glad it helped you!

Comment: if `$('#test').not($('#test').find('.ted-collapse'))` is what you're after, I'm completely lost ?

Comment: @adeneo it's actually `$('#test').find('.ted-collapse').not($('#test').find('.ted-panel').find('.ted-collapse'));` (where of course `$('#test')` is cached)

Comment: That's the same as `$('#test .ted-collapse').not('.ted-panel .ted-panel .ted-collapse')`, which was my first suggestion ?

Comment: @adeneo kind of, except that yours work when the target is at the root of the tree, but it seems like OP want to target on different level, the element might not always be in the first `.ted-panel`. (just a guess).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - well, I give up anyway, he claims `$('#test').not($('#test').find('.ted-collapse'))` is working in the edited question, and if it does, I've completely misunderstood the question !

Comment: @adeneo huh, yeah, didn't see that. A mystery to me as well...

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way too:

```
$('.ted-panel .ted-collapse:not(#test.ted-panel .ted-panel .ted-collapse)')
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1bcLts7p/1/)

Comment: That would not work, it will get all `.ted-collapse`. It is not because you exclude the parent from you selector that it will exclude the children.

Comment: I think now it's as OP wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `>` selector

> The element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent. Note: Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected.

```
$('#test > .ted-collapse')
```

Comment: .ted-collapse is not guaranteed to be an immediate child of .ted-panel

Comment: I took that to mean that it might come after ted-panel in the dom but still be a child of #test

Comment: @ScottMurphy no, sry if wasn't clear. Not necessarily immediate child of #test either.

Answer (score 0):

Get `#test`, find elements classed as `.ted-collapse`, but exclude elements that are direct children of elements that are direct children of `#test`:

```
$('#test').find('.ted-collapse:not(#test > .ted-panel .ted-collapse)');
```

Or, if `#test` isn't the right initial selector, maybe

```
$('div.ted-panel:first-child').find('.ted-collapse:not(div.ted-panel:first-child > .ted-panel .ted-collapse)');
```

[See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/gzjvsyb3/ for working examples.](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/gzjvsyb3/)

Comment: prob is it's not always #test..although I think there will always be an id. So this might work.

Comment: I added a variation of the selector to the jsFiddle.